# Queue Management Algorithm With "Ages"

Tags: queueing

Imagine we are running a physiotherapy clinic, working 5 days a week. The overall number of treatments given in a day is $k$, and the daily treatments are randomly drawn among the registered patients. Every week, a new batch of patients is registered to the clinic. Each patient needs to get their series of 10 treatments, but are limited to 1 per day. After getting their 10 treatments, they are released from the clinic.

This is our starting point. We would like to strike balance between the need to release clients ASAP and the need to serve all clients (we don't want to keep them waiting in vain). In general, this is the rationale between randomly allocating the treatments.

So assume that in week 1 the clinic was first opened, and $n_1$ patients were registered. The expected number of weekly treatments per patient is $\frac{5k}{n_1}$.

In week 2, a new batch of $n_2$ patients came in. Now, the expected number of weekly treatments per patient is reduced to $\frac{5k}{n_1+n_2}$, and this would continue to decrease with each week passing. This decrease means it would take a VERY long time for the week 1 patients to get released. We would like to solve this by somehow prioritizing those clients of higher "age".

My initial thought was going for some kind of weighted lottery (like the NBA draft) - rather than sampling (without replacement) $k$ times our of a jar with 1 ball per patients, giving each patient a number of balls befitting their "age" in the queue - that is, in week 1 all of the week 1 patients get 1 ball each. In week 2, all of the $n_1$ week 1 patients get 2 balls each, while each of the $n_2$ 'newcomers' get only 1 ball each. This way, the expected number of treatments for the week 1 patients would be $\frac{2\cdot5k}{2n_1+n_2}$, to theoretically it is supposed to give them a higher chance of getting selected (assuming $n_1,n_2$ are of the same magnitude). Of course, if a patient has more than 1 ball in the jar and they get selected, then their other ball is instantly eliminated from the jar.

Also, the factor of 2 is completely customizable. We can use a factor of $d$, which means that in the $a^{th}$ week the expected number of treatments for a week 1 patient would be

$$\frac{d^{a-1}\cdot 5k}{\sum_{i=1}^{a}{d^{a-i}n_i}}$$

However, this is just an thought at the moment. Is there any known algorithm for managing this kind of queue, where we prioritize by age?

Comment: When you say that "*Every week, a new batch of patients is registered to the clinic*", are you saying that they come all at once (e.g. on Mondays), or that throughout the week more patients get registered? If it is the latter then I need more information about what that process should look like.